# SSL timeout with pip3 install

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

I am trying to install [jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) using `pip3 install jsonschema`
but I get the following output when I run it:

```
Collecting jsonschema
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jsonschema (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for jsonschema
```

if I add the verbose flag I see

```
Collecting jsonschema
  1 location(s) to search for versions of jsonschema:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/jsonschema/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/jsonschema/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/jsonschema/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/jsonschema/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/jsonschema/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (3): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/jsonschema/'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (4): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/jsonschema/'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (5): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/jsonschema/'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/jsonschema/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (6): pypi.python.org
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/jsonschema/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/jsonschema/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jsonschema (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for jsonschema
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for jsonschema
```

If I run `pip3 install <package>` on an already installed package I get the same output but with the different package name.
I'm not sure what to do or look for to fix this, I have not had any trouble before with `pip3 install`. Apart from a `scapy` install, which needed some additional permissions. I think there is an issue with pip on my system, but I'm not sure.

I'm running an Unbuntu VM in virtualbox, with `Python 3.6.9` and `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)`

Comment: It seems there is an error connecting to https://pypi.python.org/. Try upgrading pip with this command and install package.
>> 
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
! pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --timeout 1000 jsonschema
```